# Why is the image of a community ad with minimum score threshold missing on the basic click stats?

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

There are various [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516) on Drupal.SE. 4 of these ads meet the *minimum score threshold*. However, on the [basic click stats](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3606) page for one of these 4 ads, the image of [this specific ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3614/39516) is not shown (only its *'Score'*, *'Created'* and *'Clicks per day'* is shown).

Here is the actual source of that specific ad:

```
[![PlaceToBe for Drupal module recommendations][1]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VBOp.png
  [2]: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal?sort=newest "Ask about Drupal module recommendations at SoftwareRecs.SE ..."
```

If you browse the source of `https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3606`, the part related to this specific ad looks like so:

```
<a href="http://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/ct/3614?url=&s=a596fb223a8b22bb81d4e68e482126c6384cb492834bc2fbd238cd653f4d4e50" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<img src="" alt="" title="" width="300" height="250"></a><br>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                            Score: 7<br>
                            Created: Feb 8 at 14:07<br>
                            Clicks per day: 1.37 (152 total)
                        </div>
```

Note the empty `src=""` in it (the actual image URL, i.e. `https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VBOp.png` is missing in it). And since that src is empty, there is no way you can click on the (missing) image.

**Question**: What's causing this issue, and what can be done to get it to work again?

Note: it'd also be interesting to know/find out "if" there is any impact of this visibility issue when this specific ad is actually displayed on Drupal.SE (if it is shown similar to the [basic click stats](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3606), it won't be visible either).

Comment: [Revision 7 of that post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3614/revisions) adds alt text to the link. That is the only thing I can see that sets it apart from the other qualifying ads. Perhaps that is related to the issue?

Comment: @JasonC you're right about that "alt text" addition. I was thinking about that also, and actually I could just go "edit" that post (to undo revision 7) and see what happens. But "if" that's the actual reason what causes it, then such edit would somehow invalidate my question here, no? Would be nice if there was a "fully functional" ***sandbox.SE*** site that could be used for such kinds of testing. PS: how about I'd just (as a test) apply a similar change to another ad of mine (and see what happens in the next 24 hours or so, and then rollback)?

Comment: In what universe does it ever make sense to not attempt to fix a problem because it might "invalidate" a [tag:support] request?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Jason C's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/962258) about the change in [revision 7 of that specific ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3614/7), I performed a similar edit in [revision 3 of another ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3616/3). I.e. by temporary also adding some alt text to the link of that ad. After I applied this edit, I checked the [basic click stats](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3606) page also, and sure enough: that ad started to suffer the very same problem. To complete my experiment I performed a rollback of that temporary edit.

And inspired by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/962262) I fixed "my" issue by a rollback to [revision 6 of the specific ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3614/6) where I first noticed this issue.